# how to call External URL as getJSON when i submit Form Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, getjson

Please help I tried everything cant get this simple code running 
this is my html

HTML form:

```
<form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="" class="hpi check">
<label for="licencePlate" title="Enter vehicle registration"> </label> 
<input id="licencePlate" maxlength="9" name="licencePlate" type="text" value="mt09nks" /> 

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="searchButton">Click to Check</button>

</form>
```

Java script:
If u put the Json code in document.ready function it works fine and return the data on page refresh. but when i try to call it on a button click it does not return anything.

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhr.open('get', url, true);
                                xhr.responseType = 'json';
                                xhr.onload = function() {
                                    var status = xhr.status;
                                    if (status == 200) {
                                    resolve(xhr.response);
                                    } else {
                                    reject(status);
                                    }
                                };
                        xhr.send();
                        });
                    };

            $('#searchButton').click(function(event) {

                getJSON('https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/DvlaSearch?licencePlate=mt09cna&apikey=DvlaSearchDemoAccount').then(function(json) {
                    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + json.make); 
                    result.innerText = json.make; // display
                }, function(status) { //error detection....
                  alert('Something went wrong.');
                });     


         });
```

The above javascript works fine when I run it in document.ready but when i use to call it with button click even it gives alert message - Something went wrong.

I m just using a demo from DVLA to get the details. Which i will use it display.
A user will input the vehicle registration number and search the car details.
but for example only mt09nks will work. plz guide me where I am making mistake. 
Thanks in Advance.
The above code I found in Stackoverflow and it works fine when called directly but doesnt work when i call after i click a button.

Please check where I am making mistake.

Comment: should use `$.ajax()`

Comment: Can you share the error message with us?

Comment: Sir It just return me function status value. that is  the alert value  "Something went wrong"  I think there is something wrong the way i call the function cause when i click the submit button i see the GET parameter on my URL but there is also a second parameter and it is not passed . that is the  apikey=DvlaSearchDemoAccount'    How can i pass both to my Jquery which i submit the form

Comment: You should use `$('#searchForm').submit(...)` to listen for a form submission, not a button click.

Comment: I tried this as well but no result. Is it possible can u give me the code for the html and Javascript that you would like me to write. Plz thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON
```

should be

```
getJSON(
```

I think you want to call the method that you have created right ?

You seem to be calling the method that is provided by `jQuery`

Comment: Yes i changed that but still no change. now the method getJSON is not being called. I think I need to pass both parameter and when i click submit button only one parameter is passed. dont know how to do it. amy help wpould be much appreciated

Comment: Please anybody who can answer me I just want to call this External  URL after I submit my search form and get the JSON out put